# Excel: Comparing between tables while checking data validation

Tags: excel

I have two tables; **Table1** and **Table2**.

**Table1** has two columns; ***"Sport"*** and ***"Target Miles"***

**Table2** has two columns; ***"Sport"*** (Data Validation -drop down menu for Table1[Sport]) and ***"Miles"***

I want to compare the *"Miles"* to the *"Target Miles"*, problem is, I have multiple sports such as "*Running, Walking and Rowing"* with different *"Target Miles"*

**For example** when I choose *"Running"* as a sport in *Table2* I want it to compare the *"Miles"*-value to the *"Target Miles"* Value of *"Running"* and color code the cell according to it. What kind of function do I need for this?

The best solution I've been able to find is an insanely long IF-function that doesn't support new entries into Table1's "Sports"

In other words: I want the "Target Miles" of a chosen sport as the high point when comparing "Miles" to the "Target Miles".

Comment: Look into VLOOKUP and/or INDEX/MATCH

Answer (score 0):

Use vlookup in table2 to fetch information about "Target Miles" from table1. Assume, that tables are created in columns A:B. Here is the formula that you need to add to column "C" in table2 to get information about "Target Miles" from table1: =VLOOKUP(A2;'Table 1'!A:B;2;0).

[image]